# Possibility to recover from majority of C:\windows being deleted

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, disaster-recovery

So I have an interesting and somewhat fun scenario. A developer was working on some scripts that have worked in the past when run by him which deleted files in the working directory, but supposedly when run through another user account it attempted to delete files from C: instead from a Windows 2012 R2 box.

Thankfully this is a development server, so it isn't the end of the world, but unfortunately we have no snapshot available. This is a VM, and the group that manages it is not able to use the recovery media available with the Windows installation files.

The server is still running(if you can call it that), but the Windows folder is only ~1.4GB. Registry appears to be intact, and I can still access services.msc remotely. Funny enough, the services for the application running on this server are also still running too so we could still use it for development with the network shared drives. I have also made a snapshot including memory so I can bring it back to this state at any point.

At this point we are likely going to just start over with a new server, but I was thinking through if recovery with this situation is even possible? I am trying to copy everything from C:/windows from another server that is identically configured, skipping any existing files, but I don't expect that to work. RDP does not work even after restarting the services. The group managing our VMs said the console connection does not work either.

Comment: Even if you did manage to restore most of the missing files, I think it would be impossible to trust all the files were restored properly. Just start over.

Comment: Right, that is the plan. This was more of an exercise of is it possible versus treating this as a true recovery. It would also make re-configuring the new server easier with comparing the existing setup when creating the new.

Comment: An repair installation ("in-place upgrade") would *probably* work and might save at least some of the existing content.  I'd try it on a clone rather than the original though.

Comment: Thanks, I think that would work as well, but that was along the lines of what I had mentioned using the Windows recovery media... Didn't know the best way to phrase that without sounding like I was talking about the built in Windows recovery options. Unfortunately the area that manages our VMs is unwilling or unable to do this. Thanks for the suggestion though!